# How can i disable an iframe element permanently for a website?

Tags: html, iframe

i been on a website recently and there's an iframe ads box which annoy me, there's any extension or any way i can auto disable it when i go on that website? like everytime i go on that website i have to manually delete the iframe by myself

and this is the iframe but i will delete the website link inside it:

```
<iframe id="ads_iframe" src="http://www.domain.com/ads/sidebar" width="300" style="width:300px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Use an ad blocker program or an extension.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
Using internet explorer you can disable iframes temporarily. That is the best I could do.

**1** GOTO Contro Panel -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level

**2** Scroll down to **Launching Programs and files in an IFRAME** radio button and click disable

**3** Apply settings

---

I found this [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/block-iframes-websites-51694.html) and this should get you where you need to go.

**Internet Explorer**
Click "Start" and "Internet Explorer" to launch your browser.

Select "Tools" and "Internet Options" from the browser menu. Click to highlight the "Security" tab.

Choose "Internet" for the zone and click "Custom level..." to edit the security options for this browser on the Internet.

Scroll down to the Miscellaneous category and click "Disable" under "Launching programs and files in an IFRAME." Click "OK" twice to save and activate your changes.

**Firefox**
Click "Start" and "Mozilla Firefox" to launch the browser.

Type "about:config" (without the quotes here and throughout) into the browser's address bar and press "Enter." Click "Yes" to confirm that you want to make changes to the Firefox configuration.

Type "browser.frames.enabled" in the search box and press "Enter."

Double-click the "browser.frames.enabled" entry to change the value from "true" to "false." Do not make a change if the value is already "false." Close the "about:config" window or tab.

**Google Chrome**
Install the NotScripts plugin in Chrome by clicking the wrench-shaped icon, choosing "Settings..." and clicking "Extensions."

Click "Get more extensions..." to display the Chrome Web Store. Type "Notscripts" in the search box and press "Enter." Click the "Add to Chrome" button next to the NotScripts result on the screen, then click "Add" to confirm.

Follow the onscreen instructions to set a password for the extension and change the setup options according to your preferences.

I Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't want to block just the **website**, i want to block the **iframe**

Comment: Please see update. In chrome you will need extension

Comment: that plugin "Notscripts" is not even on the extension store anymore, thanks for helping

Comment: Well if you're trying to watch streaming videos I would disable iframes through another browser.

Comment: I will try that, thanks and it was actually a website which doesn't show full screen because of sidebar ads and when you remove that useless iframe it will become full screen, i had to do it manually everytime i reload or go to the website so i loved to have a plugin that removes it by itself when i enter the website.

Comment: Sorry wasnt more help. I installed noscript a long time ago and I couldnt remember if it still worked. I stream football games from europe (stupid Comcast doesnt offer NFL package) and I kind of knew thats where you were headed. I'll be doing the same thing this weekend I'll give it a try and let ya know how it works. Mine isn't full screen either lol.